# SQL DATEDIFF Not working?

Tags: sql, t-sql, datediff

I am running a simple DATEDIFF query but it doesn't seem to calculate the days properly or i'm doing something wrong.

If I run

```
PRINT DATEDIFF(Day, 2010-01-20, 2010-01-01)
RETURN 19
```

Which is correct. If i change the month in the first date to Feb (02) I get something strange.

```
PRINT DATEDIFF(Day, 2010-02-20, 2010-01-01)
RETURN 20
```

Now shouldn't it be 48 or something?

Can anyone see what i'm doing wrong or is this not the correct function to be using if I want the No of days between these dates?

I've tried taking one date from the other:

```
PRINT (2010-02-20) - (2010-01-01)
RETURN -20
```

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks
J.

Comment: @James - no it should not be 48...you are supposed to put the larger date as the last parameter.  Otherwise the result is negative.  Dont forget the ' ' either.  See my answer below.

Comment: I didn't meant 48 exactly 'shouldn't it be 48 or something' i just did a quick calculation in my head.

Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing quotes

```
PRINT DATEDIFF(Day, '2010-01-01', '2010-02-20')
```

You're getting 20 because

```
2010 - 1 - 1 = 2008
2010 - 2 - 20 = 1988

2008 - 1988 = 20
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run it this way:

```
SELECT  2010-02-20, 2010-01-01
```

you will see

```
1988  2008
```

which are results or the integer operations that you put here.

Enclose the date constants into single quotes:

```
SELECT  DATEDIFF(Day, '2010-02-20', '2010-01-01')

--
-50
```

Answer (score 1):

```
PRINT DATEDIFF(Day, '2010-01-10', '2010-02-20')
```

That takes 2nd date - first date. Don't forget ' '.

Answer (score 1):

It works if you surround your dates with apostrophes -

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, '2010-02-20', '2010-01-10')

-41
```